# CircuiTikZ: draw transformer without conductors going to the side

Tags: nodes, circuitikz

I would like to draw a transformer in CircuiTikZ without the small parts of conductor going to the sides.

Left: Current situation. Right: What I want.

[image: Transformer. Left: Current situation. Right: What I want.]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,cuteinductors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[bth]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (0,0) node[rground] {}
        to [vsourcesin, l^=$F_A$] (0,2)
        to [generic, l_=$Z_A$] (0,4)
        to [short, i^>=$V_S$] (1,4)
        to [short] (1,3)
        (2,3) node[transformer]{}
        (1,1) node {}
        to [short] (1,0)
        to [short] (0,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Position1.}\label{fig:position1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use the `node` syntax with `transformer`, but rather `cute inductor`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx,cuteinductors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[bth]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
        (0,0) node[rground] {}
        to [vsourcesin, l^=$F_A$] (0,2)
        to [generic, l_=$Z_A$] (0,4)
        to [short, i^>=$V_S$] (1,4)
        to [short] (1,3)
        to[cute inductor] (1,1)
        to [short] (1,0)
        to [short] (0,0);

    \draw (2.5,0)
        to [short] (2.5,1)
        to[cute inductor] (2.5,3)
        to [short] (2.5,4);
    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Position1.}\label{fig:position1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: "Left: Current situation. Right: What I want." I think you have switched left and right. `:)`